# How to pass data from fragment to recycler view using interface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

I know that I can pass data from `RecyclerView` to `fragment` easily, but I want to do other way around. I want to trigger an `interface` from fragment and have that `interface` implemented in `ViewHolder` for `RecyclerView`. This is my `interface` and `ViewHolder`.

```
interface ExampleListener{
    fun onListen()
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), ExampleListener {

    ...

    override fun onListen() {
        // Do something
    }

    ...

 }
```

I don't know how to trigger this `interface` from `fragment`. I know that if I was trying to pass data to `activity` I would trigger `interface` like this:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    if (context is ExampleListener) {
        exampleListener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(requireContext().toString() + "must implement ExampleListener")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific use case, what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @mightyWOZ every RecyclerView item has a download button which downloads something (picture) and when the downloading has begun I want to show ProgressBar and hide button visibility. I cannot instantiate viewModel with hilt in ViewHolder so I was thinking that this was the better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it to update your interface so that the function accepts a callback

```
interface ExampleListener{
    fun startDownloadAndListen(onComplete: () -> Unit)
}
```

Now in adapter when you start download on button click, simply pass this callback, which will be invoked when download completes

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.visibility = View.GONE
    // Show progress bar
    listener.startDownloadAndListen { 
        // hide progress bar etc.
        button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
     }
 }
```

finally implement `ExampleListener` in your Activity as

```
override fun startDownloadAndListen(onComplete: () -> Unit) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val result = viewModel.startDownload()   // Start and wait 

        // Once result is available then call the onComplete
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onComplete() }
    }
}
```